# bootstrap-table don't work with RouterLink

Tags: bootstrap-table, angular-routerlink

In the navbar like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/users">Usuário< / a>
```

works correctly all properties from bootstrap-table, but reload the page

And when used **routerLink** from angular, like:

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/users">Usuário</a>
```

the bootstrap-table properties do not work. need F5 to work

All css and js loaded by cdn on index.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that I have two bootstrap-tables with the same id. So I just changed the id in one table and it works perfectly.